# A Nancy route is available, but still it returns 404

Tags: c#, nancy

I am trying to get Nancy to load routes based on data on disk (I read dirs and make routes based on those):

```
public class StaticModule : NancyModule {
       public static string[] RegisteredApps;

       public StaticModule() {
            foreach (string app in RegisteredApps) {
                Get[app + "{file*}"] = parameters => SendFile(app, parameters);
                Get[app] = parameters => SendFile(app, parameters);
            }
        }
}
```

Then in my calling code, I initialise the statics:

```
StaticModule.RegisteredApps = { "test1", "test2" };
NancyHost h = new NancyHost();
h.Start();
```

By using breakpoints, I can see the `StaticModule` is initialised during the call to `new NancyHost()`. I reckon this is where the route cache is built.

And indeed, using the Nancy interactive diagnostics, I can see the routes. So far so good.

However, when I try to access one of the routes, I get a 404, without the `StaticModule`'s constructor even called.

Where does this go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's failing? I've just run same here and it works just fine - though I think you may well be meaning to change

```
Get[app + "{file*}"] = ...
```

To

```
Get[app + "/{file*}"] = ...
```